# Add String with several lines into PdfAcroField multiline

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I added string into PdfActoField from PDF document like this:

```
PdfSharp.Pdf.AcroForms.PdfAcroField fieldLocation = fields["location"];
PdfSharp.Pdf.AcroForms.PdfTextField txtFieldLocation;
if ((txtFieldLocation = fieldLocation as PdfSharp.Pdf.AcroForms.PdfTextField) != null)
                {
                    txtFieldLocation.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                    txtFieldLocation.MultiLine = true;

                    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("John Doe");
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append("Text from new line1");
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append("Text from new line2");
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append("Text from new line3");
                    txtFieldLocation.Text = sb.ToString();
                }
```

My string is added but into one line.
Also I tried to add string with multiple lines using "\r\n" but still without success
Some proposal how I can to add string with multiple lines?

Comment: did you get this working ?

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me.

```
var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("John Doe");
sb.AppendLine("Text from new line1");
sb.AppendLine("Text from new line2");
sb.AppendLine("Text from new line3");
txtFieldLocation.Value = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfString(sb.ToString(), PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfStringEncoding.Unicode);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `AppendLine` instead of `Append`